# Xcode auto manage code signing in team development

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm now using Xcode's auto manage code signing for both development and distribution.
But another developer in my team failed to archive with error "missing private key".
It seems he should install the p12 file exported from my MacBook that created the distribution certificate. And download the certificate from the Apple's developer center.

Is that the right process for team development?
Or there is another right or recommended way to manage the code sign in team development?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to create a provisioning profile from your MacBook, then you should distribute it to your other developers.

Answer (score 1):

A p12 file contains public and private keys.
Downloading from Apple's developer page will only provide public key.
You have to export p12 file from the person's computer who created that file.
Store it somewhere secure then send to your teammate.